# The WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier key in your WatchKit app's Info.plist must not be present for standalone WatchKit apps

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos, watchconnectivity

I was building a standalone watch only application and I want to convert it to a dependant watch application since I need to use watch connectivity to exchange some data within the paired devices. So is it possible to directly convert this existing watch only application in the same project without creating a new target in my IOS project? Please if it is can anyone specify the instructions on how to do so?

And I also tried adding the companionbundleidentifier and it fails with the error

```
The WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier key in your WatchKit app's Info.plist must not be present for standalone WatchKit apps
```

and I am sure there is more than this to be done if I want to convert the app

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to revert independence of a watch app. You will have to add one to the iOS project directly.

source: [Reverting from an Independent Watch app, to one that is dependent on an iPhone app](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/130351)